# Add a parent tag using XML linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hello what I want is add another parent tag after the items tag

Here is the example XML:

```
<parent>
  <items>
    <book>
      <pen></pen>
     </book>
  </items>
</parent>
```

and here is the desired output:

```
<parent>
  <items>
   <paper>
    <book>
      <pen></pen>
    </book>
   </paper>
  </items>
</parent>
```

and here is my code.  What's wrong with this?

```
string xml = "<parent><items>" +
                "<book>" +
                "<pen>" +
                "</pen>" +
                "</book>" +
                "</items></parent>";



XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
var books = doc.Descendants("items").Elements().First();
doc.Element("items").Add(new XElement("paper", books));
books.Remove();

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

It only gives me error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

pointing to `doc.Element("items").Add(new XElement("paper", books));`

the answer below which i marked as checked worked in the example xml

but when i used using the long xml it doesn't work anymore

here is the link of the long xml

http://pastebin.com/nb6Pk8bX

and here is the output

http://pastebin.com/WkZEgUYy

and here is the code im using

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(reader);
                var books = doc.Descendants("Layout").Elements().First();
                books.Ancestors().First().Add(new XElement("Page", books));
                books.Remove();
```

the `page` tag became the parent. not the `layout` tag

```
document>
  <Page>
    <Layout>
```

Comment: Why are you removing books?  It is causing the error.

Comment: i commented the books.Remove(); but its still the same. it gives me the same error

Comment: Check if doc.Element("items") returns proper value.

Comment: Element() accepts a tag name, it's not an XPath expression...

Comment: doc.Element("items") returns null.

Comment: Console.WriteLine(doc.Element("items")); returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var books = doc.Descendants("items").Elements().First();
books.Ancestors().First().Add(new XElement("paper", books));
books.Remove();
```

Comment: please see the updated question. the code above doesn't work on the long xml. i dont know why.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this, first remove books next add  `XElement` and add again books it's give your destination xml

```
string xml = "<parent><items>" +
             "<book>" +
             "<pen>" +
             "</pen>" +
             "</book>" +
              "</items></parent>";



 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
 Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
 var books = doc.Descendants("items").Elements().First();
 doc.Element("parent").Element("items").Element("book").Remove();
 doc.Element("parent").Element("items").Add(new XElement("paper",books));


Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

**Edit** if you dont know first tag name you can use `Root`

> Gets the root element of the XML Tree for this document.

```
      doc.Root.Element("items").Element("book").Remove();
      doc.Root.Element("items").Add(new XElement("paper",books));
```

**Edit2** *"if the tag after the "items" tag is not a parent tag?"*

```
        doc.Descendants("items").Elements("book").Remove();
        doc.Descendants("items").First().Add(new XElement("paper", books));
```

Comment: it worked. but it works if i have a parent tag named parent. Sometimes the parent tag name differ, sometimes the parent tag name may become "library". How can i do that? thank you

Comment: sorry another question. what if the tag after the "items" tag is not a parent tag? if its inside a long tree? (inside many elements) sorry if my question is not clear